# Matplotlib - error with monospace fonts and FormatterWarning

Tags: python, matplotlib

There hasn't been any change of the code that was working, but now I am getting this error, and I have no idea what to do about it:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1224: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['monospace'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: Locator attempting to generate 20001 ticks from 0.0 to 100.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS
  FormatterWarning,
```

Comment: Is the monospace font still installed? Also - the `FormatterWarning` is pretty straight forward in telling you what's wrong.

Comment: I think it's a red herring. The exact same code worked fine with no warnings. Btw, how do I solve the monospace font issue?

Comment: We can't help you with out code.

Answer (score 0):

This line did the trick for me.

```
sudo pacman -S dina-font
```

Here the web-page of the font.

http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Jibz/Dina/index.html

If you are not on Linux you will have to download and store the file in the appropriate folder. These are:

```
#  OS Font paths
MSFolders = \
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'

MSFontDirectories   = [
    r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts',
    r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Fonts']

X11FontDirectories  = [
    # an old standard installation point
    "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/",
    "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts",
    # here is the new standard location for fonts
    "/usr/share/fonts/",
    # documented as a good place to install new fonts
    "/usr/local/share/fonts/",
    # common application, not really useful
    "/usr/lib/openoffice/share/fonts/truetype/",
    ]

OSXFontDirectories = [
    "/Library/Fonts/",
    "/Network/Library/Fonts/",
    "/System/Library/Fonts/",
    # fonts installed via MacPorts
    "/opt/local/share/fonts"
    ""
]
```